# Merge Sort meaning of a bit part of code

Tags: algorithms, sorting, integers, mergesort

I am studying this part for a merge sort implementation:

```
void mergeSort(int arr[], int l, int r) {
if (l < r)
{
    // Same as (l+r)/2, but avoids overflow for
    // large l and h
    int m = l+(r-l)/2;

    // Sort first and second halves
    mergeSort(arr, l, m);
    mergeSort(arr, m+1, r);

    merge(arr, l, m, r);
}}
```

What is the meaning of:

```
    // Same as (l+r)/2, but avoids overflow for
    // large l and h
    int m = l+(r-l)/2;
```

in the code?
Why can't I use `(l+r)/2`? (I didn't understand the comment)

Answer (score 1):

Because of [integer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow), `(l+r)/2` won't  actually compute the midpoint like we want in some special cases.  See
 https://stackoverflow.com/q/17358806/781723 and https://ai.googleblog.com/2006/06/extra-extra-read-all-about-it-nearly.html for details.